# When is “la mia madre” correct?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, articles

The sentence *La mia madre è una segretaria* has been marked wrong, but I don't understand why. I thought that, when describing a single family member, the article is optional, so using both *la* and *mia* should be correct.

Apparently it's not the case. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Italian the article is not used with single persons, with respect to family names, and the possessive adjectives, if there's no further specification:

- *tuo fratello*, but *il tuo fratello minore*
- *mio zio*, but *il mio zio d'America* (the one who lives in America)
- *mia madre*, but *la mia madre adottiva*
- *suo padre*
- *i tuoi cugini*
- *le sue cognate*

There is no hard and fast rule for the article when a specification is used, though, so also *tuo fratello minore* and *mio zio d'America* can be used. The important aspect is that *without specification* the article is refused.

This doesn't apply to other living beings, persons or not: one says *il mio cane* and never *mio cane*.

You can surely find the article used in old texts; for instance, the old translation of John's Gospel had (19:26-27, CEI/Bibbia di Gerusalemme)

> <sup>26</sup>Gesù allora, vedendo la madre e lì accanto a lei il discepolo che egli amava, disse alla madre: «Donna, ecco il tuo figlio!». <sup>27</sup>Poi disse al discepolo: «Ecco la tua madre!». E da quel momento il discepolo la prese nella sua casa.

The most recent translation (Nuova Riveduta) has instead

> <sup>26</sup>Gesù dunque, vedendo sua madre e presso di lei il discepolo che egli amava, disse a sua madre: «Donna, ecco tuo figlio!» <sup>27</sup>Poi disse al discepolo: «Ecco tua madre!» E da quel momento, il discepolo la prese in casa sua.

The article in the old version is at least antiquate.

There are exceptions: *mamma* and *babbo/papà* tend to attract the article and  *la mia mamma*, *il mio papà* are frequently heard. Actually *il mio babbo* is the only used form and *mio babbo* would be deemed incorrect. Whether adding the article with *mamma* or *papà* depends on regional background: personally I'd never say *la mia mamma* or *il mio papà*.

Comment: Exceptions: the somewhat childish expressions "la mia mamma" and "il mio papà".

Comment: @karoshi Thanks for the comment, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: "Prendi il tuo Gustavo se vuoi e non mi dire più niente dei tuoi corteggiatori!" Non è possibile?

Comment: @Evgeniy Perché non dovrebbe essere possibile? *Gustavo* è un nome proprio, non un nome comune come *madre* o *fratello*.

Comment: I would not use the article even with _tuo fratello minore_ and _mio zio d'America_, even if I would use it in _il mio fratellino_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno In some context, the article is needed, when you want to point to a particular *fratello minore* or *zio d'America*.

Comment: @egreg Cioè "tuo fidanziato" non prenderebbe un articolo? E "tuo dentista" se qualcuno sempre va a un particolare dentista? Mi riferisco alla specificazione "single persons".

Comment: @Evgeniy The discussion is about relatives (*parenti*), which *fidanzato* and *dentista* aren’t.

Comment: @egreg I couldn't have known that the discussion might be held to be constrained to relatives. Anyway, as far as I know, *inquilini* make part of the phenomenon. They are not relatives either, although they do share the house with the landlord.

Comment: @Evgeniy I would never say “mio inquilino” without the article.

Comment: @egreg Okay, thank you.